# Can I Write Aspect for my Junit Test Cases in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-aop, spring-test

I have a branch of Test cases that are using the same code repeatedly for different test scenarios/methods. It's like infra related maintenance code. Suppose need to validate some business logic before we need to perform some infra-related operation. Same after the execution of business logic like cleaning all the infra-related configs. Thought we can use Aspects. As our main services are written in spring boot.

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true) 
public class RegressionTest{

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void Test1(){
    
    }
    
    @Test
    @Order(2)
    public void Test2(){
    
    }
    
    @Test
    @Order(3)
    public void Test3(){
    
    }
    
    @Test
    @Order(4)
    public void Test4(){
    
    }
    
    @Test
    @Order(5)
    public void Test5(){
    
    }
    
    @Test
    @Order(6)
    public void Test6(){
    
    }

}
```

In the above example suppose want to run some common code before and after some test cases with the different values( 1 , 5 use some maintenance code with a different activity, and 2,6 use some different ). Depends on the test case. I planning to use Aspect so that no need to write same code repeatedly. Please suggest if you have a better suggestion or how can I use aspect-oriented programming in this scenario.

Comment: why not seperating 2,6 to a different class and then use junit's `@BeforeAll` / `@BeforeEach` ?

Comment: We run our test suits in the jenkin pipeline. Jenkin pipeline does not support different test classes

Comment: hmm really ? , how is that configured ? usually what i do in a jenkins pipeline is simply run mvn test - this will run all the tests

Answer (score 0):

You can only apply Spring AOP to Spring beans/components. I.e., your test would need to e.g. have a `@Component` annotation in order to be picked up by a correspondingly configured component scan or be instantiated in a `@Bean` factory method. I am not a Spring user, i.e. I do not have much experience in using Spring from tests either. But what I do know is that you could simply use native AspectJ, either applied by compile-time or load-time weaving, in order to achieve what you want. That would be pretty straightforward to implement. I can certainly help you, if you present an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, so I do not have to start from scratch.

If you want to use a non-AOP solution, why not simply use the existing `@BeforeAll` and/or `@BeforeEach` annotations, just like *@asafb* suggested before? I see no reason why that would not work.